# Calculating the Average Distance Between 2 Surfaces in 3D

Tags: calculus, triangles, surfaces, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral:

$$I = \frac{1}{AA'} \iint_{s'} \iint_s  |\underline{r}'-\underline{r}|  \:ds\:ds' $$

which is the distance between two surfaces, $s$ and $s'$. I'm mainly interested in evaluating this for triangles in 3D space, though quadrilaterals would also be useful. However when I use the equation for a triangle:

$$\underline{r} = \underline{a}s + \underline{b}t + \underline{c}$$
$$\underline{r}' = \underline{d}u + \underline{e}v + \underline{f}$$

I get an integral of the form:

$$I = \frac{1}{AA'} \int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1  \left(as^2 + bs + csu + dsv + et^2 + ft + ..... \right) \:ds\:dt\:du\:dv $$

then after the first two integrals Mathematica gives up and hands me a mass of terms and conditionals and can't evaluate any further.

I've had some people suggest reducing the surface integrals down to line integrals using something like Stoke's theorem but I can't find a new integrand that works. I can also calculate the above numerically but even with triangular quadrature it's computationally expensive and I'd like to be able to calculate it for a large array of triangles in a tetrahedral mesh.

Any help on this would be great. TIA

Comment: For an acadamic execise, or something practical? Consider predeterined shapes and their parallels ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Just to confirm: The first integral is of distance, and the second is of distance squared (and separately is the integral over quadrilaterals, with the area elements missing). Is the first (average distance) what you want to compute?